# How to compare previous state with new state in a selector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have two reducers, `form1` and `form2`.  I also have a 'selector' that determines whether both forms have been completed, `getAreFormsComplete`.

The state of `getAreFormsComplete` will begin as false and after `form1` and `form2` have been completed it will change to true.  The state could then go back to false if a user removes data from either form and I want to watch for that specific change.

I need to execute an action when the value of getAreFormsComplete changes from true to false (not from false to true).

How would I do this in Redux.  I would probably need the previous state of my getAreFormsComplete.

How do I compare previous state with new state in a selector and then update some state in my reducers if it changes?

*selector.js*

```
export const getAreFormsComplete = ({form1, form2}) => {
    return form1.field1.length > 0
        && form2.field1.length > 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennie, I'm pretty new to redux and react.  Yes, I'm using the connect (react-redux) helper in other parts of my applicaiton and yes, I am using reactjs (should I remove the tag?  I guess this is more of a redux only question, I just don't know if there is a more react-redux way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store.subscribe is the key to a redux and selector solution, currentAreFormsComplete variable is the previous state and I compare it to the store

```
function observeAreFormsComplete(store) {
  let currentAreFormsComplete 

  function handleChange() {
    let nextAreFormsComplete = selectors.getAreFormsComplete(store.getState())

    if (nextAreFormsComplete !== currentAreFormsComplete
      && store.getState().ui.formsUncompleted == false) {
      if (nextAreFormsComplete === false
        && currentAreFormsComplete === true) {
        store.dispatch(formsUncompleted())
      }
    }

    currentAreFormsComplete = nextAreFormsComplete
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange)
  return unsubscribe
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I think you need to do a little more reading.. The check if the formstate has changed should be in your component, and the correct place to do this is `componentWillReceiveProps`. Your selector should only be concerned by selecting the state `as is`. You connect this state to your component using the redux `connect` hoc. Your component receives the new props and `componentWillReceiveProps` allows you to compare the current props (`this.props`) with the argument `nextProps`.

For forms handling with redux there are many libraries out there which can help you with managing state (I use `redux-form` myself)

You shouldn't pass around the store (unless you don't want to use react-redux for whatever reason).

Comment: comparing old state to new state is exactly what componentWillReceiveProps is for.

Comment: Ok, I understand. There is additional info that was a little outside my original question (I was trying to keep things simple but may have missed key info). When the user puts either form back into an uncompleted state, I need to ask the user if they want to continue because doing so will delete any related data. On yes, delete the related data and put the form back to the original state, on 'no' we leave the state as is and close the modal.